# Как правильно написать запрос Get-ADUser -Searchbase?

Tags: powershell

При написании в Powershell

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter * SearchBase 'OU=Отдел, OU=Управление, OU=Департамент, 
    OU=Пользователи, OU=ИА, OU=Компания, OU=Регион, DC=test, DC=local'
```

Появляется ошибка что объект каталога не найден.

Как только я сокращаю количество OU и пишу вот так

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter * SearchBase 'OU=ИА, OU=Компания, OU=Регион, DC=test, 
    DC=local'
```

То без проблем погружается список пользователей. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать запрос  и где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего в названии OU, попробуйте скопировать правильное в выводе консоли или в оснастке AD. должно работать даже если имя OU состоит из нескольких слов

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе требуется только база, то поставь <*>.

PoSh сам найдёт путь, если он вообще есть, пример:

`Get-ADUser -Filter "DistinguishedName=*,ou=<название базы>,dc=test,dc=local"`